# How to redefine gather environment so it has justification to the left and allows to use enumerate?

Tags: environments

I need redefinition of gather (cannot be equation because of some other problem I asked about earlier on this forum) so it would have justification to the left, has no empty line after enumerate number. It may sound strange but I really need to have both labels tag and enumerating. Document has to be written in one style and I have to have enumerate in some sections where I don't have to have labels.

So, I want something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\jot}{0pt}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
       \item \begin{gather} a=b \tag{12}\label{one}\end{gather}
       \item \begin{gather}c=d \tag{lee}\label{two}\end{gather}
       \item \begin{gather}e=f \tag{bom}\label{three}\end{gather}
    \end{enumerate}
     \eqref{one} \eqref{two} \eqref{three}      
\end{document}
```

to look like this [image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\jot}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathleft}{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin5pt}
\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
\newcommand{\gatheritem}{%
    \item%
    \abovedisplayskip=0pt\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt%
    \belowdisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt%
    ~\vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
  }
\newenvironment{gatherenum}{%
    \enumerate\mathleft%
  }{%
    \mathcenter\endenumerate%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{gatherenum}
       \gatheritem \begin{gather} a=b \tag{12}\label{one}\end{gather}
       \gatheritem \begin{gather}c=d \tag{lee}\label{two}\end{gather}
       \gatheritem \begin{gather}e=f \tag{bom}\label{three}\end{gather}
  \end{gatherenum}
     \eqref{one} \eqref{two} \eqref{three}
\end{document}
```

You have to use the newly defined environment `gatherenum` instead of `enumerate`, and `\gatheritem` instead of `\item`.

**How it works**

We simulate the option `fleqn` for `amsmath` with the command `\mathleft`

```
\newcommand{\mathleft}{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin5pt}
```

and restore the centering behavior with the command `\mathcenter`

```
\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
```

Then we define a new `\item`-like command (`\gatheritem`) which removes the unwanted spacing between the item number and the equation

```
\newcommand{\gatheritem}{%
    \item%
    \abovedisplayskip=0pt\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt%
    \belowdisplayskip=0pt\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt%
    ~\vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
  }
```

Finally, we create a new environment `gatherenum` which makes use of `\mathleft` and restores `\mathcenter` at the end.

Comment: Yes, it works great. Though spacing between {\gatheritem} items could be one third shorter.

Comment: @user41766 I've modified the code. Now it should be how you want it.